# Different definitions of conformal capacity

Tags: complex-analysis, lipschitz-functions, potential-theory

A condenser is a pair $(D,E)$, where $D$ is a domain in the plane and $E$ is a compact subset of $D$. The capacity of the condenser $(D,E)$ is defined by:

$$\text{cap}(D,E) = \inf \int_{D} |\nabla u|^2 dm$$

where the infimum is taken over all Lipschitz functions $u : \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ (defined on $\mathbb{C}$) such that $u \leq 0$ on $\partial D$ and $u \geq 1$ on $E$. Also $dm$ is the usual Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{C}$.

I believe this definition would be the same if we insisted on taking the infimum over all Lipschitz functions $u$, defined on $\mathbb{C}$, such that $u = 0$ on $\partial D$ and $u = 1$ on $E$, for the following reason:

$\text{trun}(u) \stackrel{\mathrm{def}}{=} \min(\max(u,0),1)$ is still Lipschitz in the whole complex plane, and its Dirichlet integral (i.e.$ \int_{D} |\nabla \text{trun}(u)|^2 dm$) will coincide with $u$'s over $u^{-1}(0,1) \cap D$, and on $u^{-1}(-\infty,0] \cap D$ will vanish, since on this set $\nabla \text{trun}(u) = \nabla \max(u,0) = 0 $ $dm$-almost everywhere.

Similarly its Dirichlet integral over $u^{-1}[1,+\infty) \cap D$ should vanish, and therefore its Dirichlet integral over $D$ should be less than or equal to $u$'s Dirichlet integral.

However, the paper I am reading makes the following remark, which makes me think there has to be a flaw in my reasoning:

"We want to stress here that if $D = \mathbb{D}$, then the infimum can be taken over all admissible functions as above with an additional requirement that $u(z) = 0$ for all $z \in \partial \mathbb{D}$".

So it's unlikely to be true that my reasoning is sound.

Therefore I would like to know where, if in some place, my argument fails.

Comment: Which paper are you reading?

Comment: @MoisheKohan The remark I mentioned in my post is made on page 6 (first paragraph) of this https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.08107

Comment: You are correct, and I am not sure why they make that remark in the paper. Also, the definition is clearly not the correct one for unbounded domains (unless one takes the boundary in the sphere, requiring $u$ to vanish at $\infty$.) One can also take the infimum of the integral over all smooth functions $u$ compactly supported in $D$, and $\ge 1$ on $E$.

Comment: @LukasGeyer I see. Thanks a lot for your confirmation.